# Arranging JSON DATA

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I have a JSON url file, which I have grabbed the data from and wrote out to an li. The link to the JSON file is https://www.inquicker.com/facility/americas-family-doctors.json. The link to my fiddle file is http://jsfiddle.net/VVnSC/17/. I am trying to narrow down the times to the Next Available time for each location. So I only have 1 time (the next available time) for each location Brentwood, Smyrna, and Spring Hill. I am also trying to get rid of the Location name before the dash in the name so it just displays the person's name. All help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AFD TEST</title>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('https://www.inquicker.com/facility/americas-family-doctors.json',
    function(data){
    console.log(data.facility);
    $.each(data.schedules, function(i, name){
        times=''
            if (name.available_times.length){
                times='<ul>'
                $.each(name.available_times,function(i,o){
                    for (var i; i < 1; i++) {
                    times+='<li><a href="'+ name.available_times[0].url +'">'+o.when+'</a></li>'
                    }
                })
                times+='</ul>'
            }
            else{
               times='<ul><li>No Time Available</li></ul>'                    
            }
        $('#names').append('<li>' + (name.name) + times + '</li>');
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="names"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do some fancy date & time comparison, parsing and comparing the days and times.

The following parses the times and dates (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/qUvuB/6/) for how it works). This also requires `date.js` (it is added as a resource in the fiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://www.inquicker.com/facility/americas-family-doctors.json',
        function(data){

            var earliest = {};
            var doctor = {};
            var links = {};
            $.each(data.schedules, function(i, name) {
                var location = name.name.split(' - ')[0];
                var dr_name = name.name.split(' - ')[1];
                if (name.available_times.length) {
                   if (location in earliest) {   // location has already been stored.
                      var newTime = parseAvailableDate(name.available_times[0].when);
                      if (newTime.isBefore(earliest[location])) {
                         earliest[location] = newTime;
                         doctor[location] = dr_name;  
                         links[location] = name.available_times[0].url;
                      }                    
                   }
                   else {
                      earliest[location] = parseAvailableDate(name.available_times[0].when); 
                      doctor[location] = dr_name; 
                      links[location] = name.available_times[0].url;                       
                   } 
               }                    
            });
            for (i in earliest) {
                $("#names").append("<ul>Location: "+i+"<li>Doctor: "+doctor[i]+"</li><li>Time: <a href='"+links[i]+"'>"+earliest[i].toString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy H:mm tt")+"</a></li></ul>");         
            }
    });
});

function parseAvailableDate(dateString) {
    var trimmedString = dateString.replace(/^\s\s*/, '');
    var avTime=trimmedString.split(' ')[0],
        ampm=trimmedString.split(' ')[1],
        avDay=trimmedString.split(' ')[2];
    var avDate = Date.parse("next "+avDay);
    avDate.addHours(avTime.split(':')[0]).addMinutes(avTime.split(':')[1]);
    if (ampm == "pm" && avTime.split(':')[0] != "12") avDate.addHours(12);

    return avDate;
}
```

**Edit**

If the locations are fixed and you have an order in mind, just change this:

```
            for (i in earliest) {
                $("#names").append("<ul>Location: "+i+"<li>Doctor: "+doctor[i]+"</li><li>Time: <a href='"+links[i]+"'>"+earliest[i].toString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy H:mm tt")+"</a></li></ul>");         
            }
```

to:

```
            displayDetails("Brentwood", earliest, doctor, links);
            displayDetails("Smyrna", earliest, doctor, links);
            displayDetails("Spring Hill", earliest, doctor, links);
```

and create this function ([see another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/qUvuB/17/)):

```
   function displayDetails(location, earliest, doctor, links) {
            $("#names").append("<ul>Location: "+location+"<li>Doctor: "+doctor[location]+"</li><li>Time: <a href='"+links[location]+"'>"+earliest[location].toString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy H:mm tt")+"</a></li></ul>");         
   }
```

Comment: Sent you an email @ Fierytech.com

Comment: Quick question the Locations are always going to be Brentwood, Smyrna, and Spring Hill, is there anyway to always have the list populated with the available times in this order? Right now the locations change based on the available times, meaning that if Smyrna's location has the next available time it will be listed first.

Comment: @JasonWallace - edited the answer. This edit assumes the locations will not change.

Comment: Thank you so much for you input, and help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex. Something like

```
var regexp = /- (.*)/g;
var nameShort = regexp.exec(name.name);
```

The name will then be located in nameShort[1]

so in your code replace

```
$('#names').append('<li>' + (name.name) + times + '</li>');
```

with

```
var regexp = /- (.*)/g;
var nameShort = regexp.exec(name.name);
$('#names').append('<li>' + (nameShort[1]) + times + '</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp is the better option if there is a pattern

Just change this code snippet

```
$('#names').append('<li>' + (name.name) + times + '</li>');
```

with this

```
$('#names').append('<li>' + (name.name.replace(/.*?-\s/,'')) + times + '</li>');
```

Try this and 
I have update here

```
http://jsfiddle.net/VVnSC/47/
```

Comment: Your solution for the Name reduction using Regexp is sweet, Thanks.